Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system
Running Ubuntu 20.04.
sudo virt-manager

Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.
Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running.
Googled ‘Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running.’
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2480264 mentions KVM.
kvm --version

QEMU emulator version 8.0.4 (Debian 1:8.0.4+dfsg-1ubuntu3.23.10.5~backport20.04.202407120432~ubuntu20.04.1)
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
sudo systemctl start libvirtd

Failed to start libvirtd.service: Unit libvirtd.service is masked.
systemctl status libvirtd

● libvirtd.service
Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit libvirtd.service is masked.)
Active: inactive (dead)
systemctl, how to unmask
sudo systemctl unmask libvirtd.service

Removed /etc/systemd/system/libvirtd.service.
sudo systemctl status libvirtd.service

Unit libvirtd.service could not be found.
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libvirt-daemon-system : Depends: libvirt-clients (= 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.20) but 10.0.0-2ubuntu8.3~backport20.04.202408270202~ubuntu20.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libvirt-daemon (= 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.20) but it is not going to be installed
qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.29) but 1:8.0.4+dfsg-1ubuntu3.23.10.5~backport20.04.202407120432~ubuntu20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
sudo apt-get install libvirt-clients

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libvirt-clients is already the newest version (10.0.0-2ubuntu8.3~backport20.04.202408270202~ubuntu20.04.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
sudo apt-get install libvirt-daemon

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libvirt-daemon is already the newest version (10.0.0-2ubuntu8.3~backport20.04.202408270202~ubuntu20.04.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Unsure how to fix broken packages.
Thank you.
sudo synaptic

Highlight All
Edit -> Fix Broken Packages
Clicked Reload
0 broken appears at bottom of window.

sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libvirt-daemon-system : Depends: libvirt-clients (= 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.20) but 10.0.0-2ubuntu8.3~backport20.04.202408270202~ubuntu20.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libvirt-daemon (= 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.20) but it is not going to be installed
qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.29) but 1:8.0.4+dfsg-1ubuntu3.23.10.5~backport20.04.202407120432~ubuntu20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
So, same issue.

The system closed this thread after stating the post from a user solved the problem. I cannot find this user's post so, please thank them. 1) dpkg --get-selections | grep held 2) no results so, good! 3) sudo aptitude install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system 4) no to keep libvirt-daemon-system at current version. 5) Accept solution to remove  libvirt-l10n; downgrade various packages (too many for this comment). 6) Leave dependency unresolved - qemu-utils recommends qemu-block-extra. 7) Accepted solution. 8) systemctl status libvirtd - successful. 10) sudo virt-manager - successful boot and login.
